# Wrong Routing by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing

We have a computer system with two network adapters on the mainboard. One leads to an internal network of the system with several devices (192.168.0.0). Another is connected to the network of the company (10.0.0.0). At the start we could ping the internal devices but not a database server (10.27.190.37) on the company network. After that i changed the routing table of windows like the picture below. After that change we could ping the database server (not in the picture) but not the internal devices (i.e. 192.168.0.21). The internal network is only connected with a switch.

On the network setting in windows we configured the interface in the net 192.168.0.0 without an interface and with the subnet mask 255.255.255.0. The other has the same subnet mask, a gateway address (10.27.166.129) and two DNS addresses. At last there are three DNS-suffixes configured.

A change in the metric of the interface didn't lead to any other result.

Can somebody help please?

[image: Network configuration and ping behavior]

Comment: Please post the output of "ipconfig /all". Your description of the network setup on the computer is a bit too strange (maybe there is a language barrier here) to make sense of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts with the routing table, we solve it on the quik way: Switch the network cables on the computer, erase all manual insertet static routes and restart the computer. After that all worked well.

Greetings Noran